# elements in I when R/I is a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have $R$ as a ring and $I$ an ideal of R such that $R/I$ is a commutative ring.

I want to show that $-ab+ba\in I$. In order to do this, what are the conditions that I need for the sum $-ab+ba$.

Since R/I is commutative, I know that $ab+I=ba+I$, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotient $R/I$ is an abelian group (as all rings are) so $(ab + I) - (ba + I) = 0 + I$.  This implies that $ab - ba \in I$.

Comment: okay, I got the exact same thing, too. So it's om that I can do this, then? I was just thinking that how does the first sentence imply that $ab-ba \in I$

Comment: The elements of the quotient ring are equivalences classes.  We have $(ab+I) - (ba+I) = (ab - ba) + I = I$.  By the equivalence relation which defines quotient rings, we have $ab-ba \in I$.  If you are still confused you should reread the definition of the quotient ring.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Definition: $x+I=y+I\iff x-y\in I.$